# How to call to java web service using php

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have web service that has written using java and its return  strcut type

When I call to a  `$OutResult = $client->__getFunctions();` its return follwing

```
Array ( [0] => PPMAccesibilityResult getPPMAccesibility(EmployeeDetails $parameters) [1] => ProjectProgressResult getProjectProgressStatusForEmployee(EmployeeYearDetails $parameters) [2] => ProjectCountForLocationResult getProjectCountForLocation(LocationYearDetails $parameters) [3] => CircularSummaryInfo getCircularSummaryInfo(DeptYearDetails $parameters) [4] => BeneficiaryProjectDetailsResult getProjectDetailsOfBeneficiary(BeneficiaryDetails $parameters) ) 1
```

When i Call to `$OutResult = $client->__getTypes();` it will return follwing

```
Array ( [0] => struct EmployeeDetails { string employeeId; } [1] => struct EmployeeYearDetails { string employeeId; string financialYear; } [2] => struct PPMWebServiceException { string message; } [3] => struct PPMAccesibilityResult { string response; } [4] => struct ProjectProgressResult { ImplementationProject projectList; } [5] => struct ImplementationProject { string charterCode; string title; string titleSinhala; string titleTamil; string completionPercentage; string deptId; string financialYear; } [6] => struct LocationYearDetails { string locationId; string financialYear; } [7] => struct ProjectCountForLocationResult { ImplementationProjectCount projectCountList; } [8] => struct ImplementationProjectCount { string programId; string programName; string programNameSinhala; string programNameTamil; string impProjectCount; } [9] => struct DeptYearDetails { string deptId; string financialYear; } [10] => struct CircularSummaryInfo { string circularId; string circularName; string introduction; string objective; string goal; string projectExecution; string projectTimeline; string contactDetails; string proposalApprovalCriteria; ProjectDetails projectList; } [11] => struct ProjectDetails { string projectId; string projectName; string indicatorName; } [12] => struct BeneficiaryDetails { string beneficiaryId; string financialYear; } [13] => struct BeneficiaryProjectDetailsResult { ImplementationProject projectList; } ) 1
```

Now when tried to call using this `$OutResult =$client->getPPMAccesibility("6");` its getting error could not find host ,but my web service working fine

How could i call to this webservice correctly using php please help

Comment: I think you have checked the function name so it's $client->getPPMAccesibility("6"); and not $client->_getPPMAccesibility("6"); , isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

just sample check whether your web-service work with this link.

http://www.service-repository.com/client/start

:)